# Disposing Camera before initialization is ready

Tags: c#, .net, camera, windows-phone-7.1, dispose

In WP7.1, If I dispose camera before it is ready, I got the following exception:

```
ExceptionObject {"Initialization canceled by .Dispose().\r\nObject name: 'Camera'."}    System.Exception {System.ObjectDisposedException}
```

How camera should be Disposed in the case I need to shutdown the page before it gets ready. I would not like to wait till cam.Initialized is called.

Comment: Never mind. I can simply ignore the UnhandledException in my case.

Comment: any success with this error? looks like i have the same